# Kuhn-Tucker conditions for inequality constraints

Tags: optimization, lagrange-multiplier, programming, karush-kuhn-tucker

So, when we solve the optimization problem using Lagrange Multiplier method, I know that lambda can be positive or negative.
Lambda is simply the rate of change in the optimal value when the constraint changes. So, I understand that lambda can be positive or negative.

Now, my question is when we have inequality constraints. In that case, why do we have the requirement that lambda should be non-negative? I could understand the math behind it. But I am not able to follow up the intuition. Simply put, if Lambda is still the rate of change with respect to the change in the constraint, then why THEORETICALLY SPEAKING can't it be negative?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: https://www-cs.stanford.edu/people/davidknowles/lagrangian_duality.pdf

Comment: Can you elaborate on what "lambda is the rate of change in the optimal value when the constraint changes" means? While I can kind of see this when writing $\partial f(x) + \lambda \partial g(x) = 0$ from $L(x, \lambda) = f(x) + \lambda f(x) = 0$, I don't see how this interpretation relates to the optimization problem.

Comment: For equality constraints $g(x)=0$ you can penalize the Lagrangian by taking $\lambda \to \infty$ whenever $g(x) > 0$, or $\lambda \to -\infty$ whenever $g(x) 
< 0$. But for inequality constraints $g(x) \le 0$ you don't need to penalize the case when $g(x) < 0$; you only need to be able to take $\lambda \to \infty$ when $g(x) > 0$.

Comment: @angryavian This is a standard result in optimisation. With lots of assumptions, of course. See https://people.duke.edu/~hpgavin/cee201/LagrangeMultipliers.pdf for an informal discussion.

Answer (score 1):

It is only under certain circumstances that the Lagrange multipliers represent the sensitivity of the optimal cost to a change in a constraint bound.

Different conventions used for the multipliers. In the context of a problem $\min \{ f(x) \mid g_k(x) \le b_k \}$, the convention I prefer is that at a local $\min$ (assuming a suitable constraint qualification is satisfied) there are **non negative** multipliers $\lambda_k$ such that
$\nabla f(x) + \sum_k \lambda_k \nabla g_k(x) = 0$ (plus complimentary slackness, etc.).

To simplify life, assume there is just one constraint $g(x) \le b$. Under lots of extra conditions, we have that the sensitivity of the optimal cost to $b$ is given by $- \lambda$. That is, the sensitivity is **non positive**.

To see why this makes sense, if you increase $b$, the feasible set gets larger and so the resulting $\min$ will be **lower** (or at least, not larger), hence the sensitivity is negative (well, non positive).

In the context of an equality constraint $h(x) = b$, note that this is exactly the same as the constraint $-h(x) = -b$, so there is no 'preferred' sign as is the case with inequality constraints. Also, note that the feasible set does not have the same containment (as in $\subset$) relationship as with inequality constraints, so one cannot expect a particular sign.